# Why can't I write numeric operation in XAML?

Tags: xaml

Sorry, if the question is too obvious.

I am working from long time in XAML but still this question is mystery for me: why can't I write numeric operation in XAML? Like 2+3 etc..

Why cannot XAML at runtime manipulate expressions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Markup languages responsible of just markup :) . You can't do that in HT***M***L also. They are not real programming languages.

You can do operations in programming languages. Java Script is a programming language,PLSQL is a programming language,c#,java ... so on, because they do operations. But HTML,XML,XAML are just expressions for how data will be present.Not how data will be calculate.

SGML is ancestor of Markup Languages.

For more information about markup languages http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markup_language

So we have,

- Programming Languages
- Markup Languages

Beside this with new standards W3C,IEEE put some rules on them and we need to obey.

Regards